# Using aria2c, is there a way to make the output filename the same as the input URL in a batch download?

Tags: bash, sh

`aria2c` has an event hook feature that runs a given script when an event occurs. Using the `--on-download-complete` param for example, is there a way to change the output file's name to its download URL? Now there may be a way to use `-o` somehow, but I don't think it will effective when handling multiple downloads. Here's an example of what I'd be using as the base command:

```sh
aria2c -i <urls> --optimize-concurrent-downloads true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using the whole URL as a filename

> is there a way to change the output file's name to its download URL

No, because file URLs contain the character `/` which is the only character that cannot be part of a filename in Linux, since it is used a as separator for paths like `path/to/dir/`.

<sub>Windows uses `\` as a delimiter, but still forbids to use `/` inside a filename.</sub>

However, you can change the `/` to something different like `|`. You can manually specify the output name for each input URL inside your input file like so:

```
domain.tld/abc/xyz/file1
 out=domain.tld|abc|xyz|file1
something.sth/abc/xyz/file2
 out=something.sth|abc|xyz|file2
...
```

To generate and use a file like this, use

```
awk '{print; gsub("/","|"); print " out="$0}' fileOfUrls | aria2c -i-
```

#### Using only the filename in the URL as a filename

I thought that aria2c already names the files like they are named in the URL. If that doesn't work, generate an input file accordingly:

```
sed 's|[^/]*$|&\n out=&|' fileOfUrls | aria2c -i-
```

Comment: personally, i think it would be better to substitute with `-` or `_`. another thing to consider while naming files is how they act in the shell. and `|` is already used for the pipes and so referring to it would need escaping or quoting.